# array of arrays ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When performing a search of shops and paginating the results (10 per page) on the left hand side of the page I need to show the list of employees (without duplicates) that work in all the shops currently displayed.

In the view I have the following but it doesn't feel like the most efficient and it shows duplicate employees

```
- @shops.each do |shop|
- shop.employees.each do |employee|
 %li = link_to "#{employee.name}", employee_path(employee)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@shops.map(&:employees).flatten.uniq.each do |employee|
  %li = link_to "#{employee.name}", employee_path(employee)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question, how can I arrange alphabetically by employee name?

Answer (score 2):

`uniq`?

```
- @shops.each do |shop|
- shop.employees.uniq.each do |employee|
 %li = link_to "#{employee.name}", employee_path(employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of query should be done at the DB rather than in-memory.

```
class Shop
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

Retrieve the employees for the given collection of shops in your controller:

```
@employees = Employee.all_by_shop_id(@shops, :order => :name)
```

Now in your view:

```
-@employees.each do |employee|
  %li = link_to "#{employee.name}", employee_path(employee)
```